# Macbook Pro crashes when I remove power while hibernated

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, crash, filevault, hibernate

I have a late 2013 Macbook Pro (`MacBookPro11,3`) running OS 10.9.3 that I want to keep as locked down as possible since I have sensitive company data on it. To that end, I have turned on FileVault, [set `DestroyFVKeyOnStandby 1 hibernatemode 25`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/39294/21703), and set a firmware password. I have turned off Wake for WiFi access, Power Nap, and graphics card switching.

This set up works most of the time. However, I have found that it always crashes under the following sequence:

- Sleep by closing the lid and then Hibernate while connected to power
- Remove power. The display backlight comes on; wait for it to go out.

Boom, no more waking, now I have to hit the power button to reboot the machine. (If I remove power but immediately open the lid, then fully wake the machine by entering the firmware password and then the FileValut password, I'm fine.)

Of course I'd like a solution that maintains the protection of the data while the computer is sleeping/hibernating, but I'd settle for theories about what the computer is trying and failing to do when power is removed while hibernating so that maybe I can figure out a solution from there.

Comment: To find out what is it trying to do, you need to open the Console in Utility and publish related time stamps here.

Comment: @Buscar웃 If the laptop never gets as far as mounting the disk, what makes you think it will be able to write anything to the Console log?

Comment: I wanted to know what is it doing during hibernate if anything, since some processes can overwrite the PMSET

Comment: If you have a reproducible crasher, why not also file a bug with Apple so it gets fixed? If you submit it to open radar, others can dupe it ;)

Comment: @bmike Filing bug reports with Apple when you're not a developer seems like a waste of time in general, and especially when you are using a feature like `hibernate 25` that is explicitly "not supported".

Comment: When an engineer gets a reproducible crash report, good things happen. Even for unsupported values. They are there for internal testing and often show problems with code that should be supported. Your call if it's worth it of course.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with my own late 2013 Macbook Pro running 10.9.3. In the end, I had to run the following commands with root privileges:

```
pmset -a darkwakes 0
pmset -a standby 0
pmset -a standbydelay 0
pmset -a lidwake 0
pmset -a acwake 0
pmset -a destroyfvkeyonstandby 1 hibernatemode 25
```

Once I did that, I found that I needed to wake the laptop by touching the power button (**pmset -a lidwake 0** disables the automatic wake-up when you open the lid) but my MacBook Pro now hibernates properly and does not crash.

I have a post on the issues I had with 10.9.2 available here:

http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/power-nap-power-management-settings-and-filevault-2/

Comment: My understanding of `standby 0` is that it would prevent the laptop from hibernating, but I want the laptop to hibernate. Reading your post I see you solved this by leaving `autopoweroff` set to 1, but then I'm thinking that (a) that will suck too much battery before kicking in and (b) my computer will be vulnerable longer.  With your configuration do you still get the grey screen password prompt every time you wake?

Comment: Yes, I get the FileVault 2 password prompt every time when I wake it from sleep.

Comment: Since you're setting the laptop to hibernate automatically rather than sleep by setting pmset to use hibernate mode 25, having standby set to 0 will not increase power drain nor will your laptop have any increased vulnerability.

Comment: Setting hibernate mode 25 does not set the laptop to hibernate automatically, it just sets the behavior when SafeSleep is called for, which is normally triggered by going into `standby`. I can't shake the feeling that you solved the problem by turning off standby and preventing your laptop from ever hibernating as well as preventing it from ever waking automatically.

Comment: There may be some misunderstanding about how these settings apply to hibernation. Here's the relevant sections of the pmset man page: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html
-----

hibernatemode = 25 (binary 0001 1001) is only settable via pmset. The system will store a copy of memory to persistent storage (the disk), and will remove power to memory. The system will restore from disk image. If you want "hibernation" - slower sleeps, slower wakes, and better battery life, you should use this setting.

Comment: STANDBY ARGUMENTS  
  
standby causes kernel power management to automatically hibernate a machine after it has slept for a specified time period. This saves power while asleep. This setting defaults to ON for supported hard-ware. harware. The setting standby will be visible in pmset -g if the feature is supported on this machine.  
  
standby only works if hibernation is turned on to hibernatemode 3 or 25.  
  
standbydelay specifies the delay, in seconds, before writing the hibernation image to disk and powering off memory for Standby.

Comment: Right, but you set `standby 0` thus setting STANDBY to OFF, so standby will not hibernate the machine regardless of the hibernate mode.

Comment: At this point, we're going around and around on this point. All I can tell you is that using these settings, my laptop does not go to sleep. It hibernates immediately instead.